# Any economical MSc to become a Quant?

Tags: education

I've finished a bachelors degree in physics, and I'm thinking of trying to get a Quant job in a few years.

I'm aware that an MSc is mandatory, however, in my view the price of the typical Financial Engineering or Quantitative Finance master in a good school is exaggerated, and in almost all job offers, they just ask for an advanced degree in any quantitative discipline.

Are there any other kind of MSc that can be useful to work as a Quant without having to pay a considerable amount? (I'm thinking about general mathematics, statistics, AI or something like that).

Many thanks!

Comment: If you live in the US, I'd recommend doing an electrical engineering graduate course at any reputable school (course 6 at MIT is excellent, and offers many advanced probability classes, including this one [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/)). In Europe, I think a good choice is any MSc in Statistics (UCL has a good one, Imperial also has a good one). A pure MSc is way better & cheaper than an MSc in Finance: I actually did an MSc in Finance at MIT, and the only useful classes I took were course 6 (i.e. electrical eng).

Comment: Ps: PhD will get you further than an MSc btw. Not having a PhD makes it more difficult to have a pure quant career (without a doctorate, you can't really publish / it's much more difficult to publish. Also, most of the quants who will interview you will likely hold a PhD, and it will be easier to build rapport if you also have a PhD). 

PPs: in general, quant finance can be done in two ways: PDEs or Probability. If you wanna be a PDE quant, do a Physics PhD, if you like probability, I'd recommend one of the courses I described above (electrical engineering, advanced stats/ prob, applied math